# EM algorithm for mixture with latent regression?

Tags: regression, expectation-maximization, mixture-distribution, latent-variable

I have in the past implemented the EM algorithm for certain cases of mixture distributions. However, I'm attempting to implement it now for a given problem that's exposing my lack of understanding of the underlying theory.

I'll try to keep the question general (hopefully not vague) so that a solution is useable in many cases. Let's imagine we desire to implement a mixture of two regressions. These two regressions can be assumed to be GAMs. Is it feasible to have the latent variables (the weights between the two components) also as a regression?

That is, is it possible to formulate the weights (the latent variable) between the two components of the mixture to also be a regression dependent on the same covariates? Would this formulation still allow for an EM approach?

Answer (score 0):

Cluster-weighted modelling may be what you want. Not sure whether this is exactly what you have in mind, but it's a mixture of regressions with covariate-dependent weights.

Mazza, A., Punzo, A., & Ingrassia, S. (2018). flexCWM: A Flexible Framework for Cluster-Weighted Models. Journal of Statistical Software, 86(2), 1–30. https://doi.org/10.18637/jss.v086.i02